# C# Android Keep thread alive on Activity Change

Tags: c#, android

I am new to Android Visual Studio. I have an app which has two Activities. It is possible as user to switch between the two Activities. The second Activity has a Thread running in the event OnCreate. The method which runs in a separate Task Thread is updating data and can take a bit more time. If the Update is running the user has still the possibilty to switch back to the first Activity. In this case I have a destroyed Update. Is there any way I can go to have that update running completly through. I need a solution how to let the thread finish its update without being stopped due to the Destroy\Close event ? Any help or idea is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: code snippet would help as question not so clear

Comment: I think it would be better if you described the problem you wish to solve.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

just implement an application class in your MainActivity.cs and run the thread from the app class